# How to go back to a question using if statement in python?

Tags: python

So i have been trying to make a simple quiz game. The problem is when a user answers wrong, i want the if statement to take me back to the question and keep asking it until the correct answer is received. For some reason, i have not been able to do it. I have also tried while loop.
Please help

```
questions = {
    1:{
        "question" : "A cat just destroyed my...?",
        "answer" : ["Plant", "plant"]
    },
    2:{
        "question" : "Physics is the branch of...?",
        "answer" : "Science" or "science"
    }
}


def quiz():
    q1 = input(questions[1]["question"])


    if q1 == questions[1]["answer"][0] :
        print("Your answer is correct")
    
    elif q1 == questions[1]["answer"][1]:
        print("Your answer is correct")
    else: 
        print("Wrong")



quiz()
```

Comment: How about using `while(true)`, if user got correct answer then use `break`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean while loop in the function? The current code will call the quiz function only once. You could make a while loop in the function that will call itself when the answer is correct. Hope this helps you (Sorry for bad english, i'm not native)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work I suppose:

```
questions = {
    1: {
        "question": "A cat just destroyed my...?",
        "answer": ["Plant", "plant"]
    },
    2: {
        "question": "Physics is the branch of...?",
        "answer": "Science" or "science"
    }
}

flag=0
def quiz():
    global flag
    while(flag==0):
     q1 = input(questions[1]["question"])

     if q1 == questions[1]["answer"][0]:
        print("Your answer is correct")
        flag+=1

     elif q1 == questions[1]["answer"][1]:
        print("Your answer is correct")
        flag+=1
     else:
        print("Wrong")
        flag=0


quiz()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loop

```
def quiz():
    while(True):
        q1 = input(questions[1]["question"])

        if q1 == questions[1]["answer"][0] :
            print("Your answer is correct")
            break
    
        elif q1 == questions[1]["answer"][1]:
            print("Your answer is correct")
            break

        else: 
            print("Wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call quiz() again if answer is wrong:

```
def quiz():
    q1 = input(questions[1]["question"])
    if q1 == questions[1]["answer"][0] :
        print("Your answer is correct")    
    elif q1 == questions[1]["answer"][1]:
        print("Your answer is correct")
    else: 
        print("Wrong")
        quiz()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a loop.

```
def quiz():
    while True:
        q1 = input(questions[1]["question"])

        if q1.upper() == questions[1]["answer"][0].upper() :
            print("Your answer is correct")
            break

    else: 
        print("Wrong")`
```

Another solution to help solve your problem with users typing both upper and lowercase letters, is to upper both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out myself with a little help from you guys
All i needed to do was to add the question again in the else statement, and that was it:

```
questions = {
    1:{
        "question" : "A cat just destroyed my...?",
        "answer" : ["Plant", "plant"]
    },
    2:{
        "question" : "Physics is the branch of...?",
        "answer" : "Science" or "science"
    }
}


def quiz():
    q1 = input(questions[1]["question"])

    while(True):
        if q1 == questions[1]["answer"][0] :
            print("Your answer is correct")
            break
        
        elif q1 == questions[1]["answer"][1]:
            print("Your answer is correct")
            break
        else: 
            print("Wrong") 
            q1 = input(questions[1]["question"])

      

quiz()
```